# How can I convince Python to traverse every sys.path entry for similarly-named imports?

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following (obviously contrived) files:

**/home/me/family.py**

```
from Brothers.Larry import *
from Brothers.Darrel import *
print(Larry)
print(Darrel)
```

**/home/me/primary/Brothers/Larry.py**

```
Larry = "Hi, my name is Larry"
```

**/home/me/primary/Brothers/Darrel.py**

```
Darrel = "Hi, I'm Larry's brother Darrel"
```

**/home/me/secondary/Brothers/Darrel.py**

```
Darrel = "Hi, I'm Larry's other brother Darrel"
```

(I also have the requisite `__init__.py` files in the `Brothers` directories)

**SCENARIO**

If I run this command:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/me/primary:/home/me/secondary python family.py
```

I get the expected:

```
Hi, my name is Larry
Hi, I'm Larry's brother Darrel
```

However, if I switch the search order of the directories:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/me/secondary:/home/me/primary python family.py
```

I get the very much unwanted result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "family.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Brothers.Larry import *
ImportError: No module named Larry
```

Not only does Python **not** override (or hide) the "primary" instance of the `Darrel.py` module with the "secondary", it appears to be caching the first instance of the `Brothers` location and never considering the second.  Is this not a valid use case?  How can I convince Python to accept this situation?  Of course, the results I'm looking for are:

```
Hi, my name is Larry
Hi, I'm Larry's other brother Darrel
```

I'm on RHEL7 with the default 2.7.5 version of Python.

Comment: This is intriguing, but I'm having a hard time understanding why you want/need to do this. And it could cause severely hard-to-debug issues if you end up using two slightly different versions of the same module at the same time and *don't* mean to.

Comment: @CrazyChucky  I'm working on the update and migration of a large production mailman installation.  The existing code was built and installed from source (after being heavily modified) rather than installed via standard package management.  We do not wish to continue this approach.  We want all patched modules to be placed in a "site" location (/usr/local perhaps) and to override the standard modules by way of appearing "in front" of them in the import search path.  We are aware of the "dangers" of this approach, but feel that it's the correct solution.  Other languages allow this behavior.

Comment: Hm. Well if the location with the patched modules is on the path first, and each patched module essentially replaces/shadows the stock version (if installed), isn't that enough? Why do you also need to fall through to the stock modules sometimes? Do you want to be able to leave parts "missing" in the patched versions? (I'm sorry, I don't mean to interrogate you. I'm just 1. interested in the problem and 2. unsure what to suggest because I apparently still don't understand the intent or constraints.)

Comment: @CrazyChucky The first directory in the sys.path is sparse and contains only the patched modules.  The patched modules should always be found before the stock modules they override.  The only "falling through" that needs to occur (that MUST occur) is to locate every other remaining stock module for which there is no overriding patched module.  This does not happen because Python effectively ignores the second "Brothers" directory in the search path as soon as it sees the first.